# LinearLayout not scrolling after adding elements Dynamically

Tags: scroll, android-linearlayout

This is my xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="www.oditorium.net.material_design_beta.fragment_layout3">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:background="#006600"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView></FrameLayout>
```

I am adding elements to LinearLayout dynamically in the code.But the page is not scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:background="#006600"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
```

in above code we fix  the size of scrollview.